# Least distance on Riemannian Manifold

Tags: optimization, riemannian-geometry

I've been doing some calculations of geodesics in different Riemannian Manifolds. More precisely I'm trying to compute, given two points on a Riemannian Manifold, the smallest distance between those points.

I started by trying to compute the distance of two points on a 2-sphere. That was easy. Then I thought to consider not a 2-sphere but a 2-sphere with some kind of a wormhole in it, something like a doughnut...

I thought of using the following metric:
$$
ds^2=(1-b(r)/r)^{-1}dr^2+r^2 d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta d\varphi^2,
$$
where $b(r)$ is some function that should describe the throat of the wormhole - as it can be seen [here](http://www.physics.uofl.edu/wkomp/teaching/spring2006/589/final/wormholes.pdf). First question: Is this correct for what I'm looking for?

Then, given this metric, the distance is given by:
$$
l=\int{ds}=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}[(1-b(r)/r)^{-1}\dot{r}^2+r^2+ r^2\sin^2\theta \dot{\varphi}^2]^{1/2}d\theta,
$$
right? And then, I should make use of the Euler-Lagrange equations...Am I correct?

Comment: It's not clear to me why $\sin\theta$ is not squared. Anyway, you should not expect to get any manageable explicit formulas by continuing your computations. But it is easy to calculate distances on the [torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) explicitly by endowing it with the flat metric: the one that comes from the quotient map $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$. Indeed, the geodesics in this metric are images of straight lines under the quotient map.

Comment: Ups, it was a typo.
Yeh I get really ugly formulas. But I just wasn't sure I was doing things the right way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Mark L. Irons posted a very nice and detailed discussion of [geodesics on round tori](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/geodesics.xhtml). More detail in the [PDF version](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf).
- Jim Belk gives simple [tips for finding geodesics](http://math.bard.edu/belk/math352/Outline%20-%20Geodesics.pdf).
- If you have access to jstor and enjoy reading old papers with lots of explicit computations, take a look at [The Geodesic Lines on the Helicoid](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1967583) by S. E. Rasor. The author derives equations for all geodesics on both catenoid and helicoid. Most of these equations involve elliptic integrals.

Comment: The first two references I already knew but the third one looks really detailed. Thank you